# Why is my custom User View column not sorting A-Z?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have added a custom column to my Users table in WordPress called **Security Answer**. I wanted to make this column sortable so I ended up with this code:

```
function trucklesoft_my_sortable_cake_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['security_answer'] = 'Security Answer';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'trucklesoft_my_sortable_cake_column' );
```

I can now click on the column heading and it appears to do some kind of sort but it is not working.

It is a text based column and some items in the column are empty but I am expecting it to sort A-Z fashion or Z-A fashion but it won't.

How do I implement the sorting logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only register the column as sortable, so the admin table headers include the necessary markup.

But the sorting logic is not implemented. You would need something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'trucklesoft_security_orderby' );
function trucklesoft_security_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() || ! current_user_can( 'edit_user' ) )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'security_answer' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','security_answer');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
    }
}
```

It's been a while since I did WP, so you may need to adjust the code a bit. And I'm assuming your "security_answer" is indeed a custom postmeta.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. the content that is displayed is extracted from the user meta data table.

Comment: To display the value I have to get item 16 from meta field key xyz. I can't sort on the whole meta value but just item 16 in the user meta array

Comment: OK. Thanks. This bit: `$query->set('meta_key','security_answer');` is that telling it to get the value of the security answer column? Or is it examining the user meta data itself?

Comment: Ok, well, as I mentioned, the user meta 'security_answer' is actually an array of information and the item I am interested in is at index 16 in that array.

Comment: That's not mentioned in your question. But even then, you cannot sort by an array item. It's simply not possible for MySQL to do that.

Comment: Well, I assumed that it would be sorted the table of data that I already have on screen. Since I already have populated the table already with the needed values. The plugin that i use for security stores this array of data so it is out of my hands. Not to worry. I will mark your answer as correct anyway!